# In iTerm, how can I change alt+delete to ignore slashes?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bash, iterm

I set up my iTerm to work a lot like OSX does in other text fields, eg <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> = `delete line backward`, <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+left arrow = "move cursor back one word" and <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> = `delete word backward`, but the way I have it, <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> in bash/iTerm doesn't count `/` as a word separator, so if I have `cd a/path/to/a/folder` and I hit <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> it deletes the whole path, instead of just `folder`.

How can I set it up so that <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> only gets rid of folder? I realize this might need a bash solution, or an iTerm solution, but I don't know which. Or maybe it needs both.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to get this to work, in iTerm preferences I had to set the key alt+backspace (or w/e you have it as) to map to these hex codes:

```
0x1B 0x08
```

If using zsh, add the following to .zshrc:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

Comment: I wanted to say thank you for this answer! Everyone had the first part, but I did not find the second part (the `.zshrc`) anywhere!